# How does unity3D go straight instead of translation after rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use unity3D to develop a rigid body. After 90 degrees clockwise rotation in the MoveRotation method, I want the object to move forward. If Vector3.forward is used, it does not go straight but shifts.

As you can see, the z-axis is the direction I'm going, and when I rotate 90 degrees in place and he's still moving toward the Z-axis, I want him to move forward, not shift

---

#### Edit with Screenshots:

As you can see, the z-axis is the direction I'm going, and when I rotate 90 degrees in place and he's still moving toward the Z-axis, I want him to move forward, not shift

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show the code for the movement, and some screenshots/video to show the issue? Though it is likely due to the way the rotation affects the object's perspective. When you rotate an object, its local axes also change, hence when you move forward now after rotating, it's new forward is now another direction;

Comment: Screenshots and code can be found below

Comment: Next time, you can edit the question you posted directly. Additionally, it is better to copy-paste the code directly instead of including it a screenshot.

Comment: In general [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

... And then I am confused .. based on your code your cube should be moving in absolute worldspace Z direction ... you are saying `I want the object to move forward. If Vector3.forward is used, it does not go straight but shifts.` which sounds like this absolute forward movement is actually what you want to happen ... do you also move this cube by physics somewhere? Or is your camera moved and therefore movement only looks off

Comment: According to the shadows I would claim you are using some sort of follow-camera .. your movement is always applied in absolute world space Z-axis direction => the movement looks off related to the camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
rb.MovePosition(tf.position + Vector.forward * 20 * Time.deltaTime);
```

moves in absolute world space Z direction, regardless of any rotation of the object.

According to the shadows in your screenshots though I would claim you are using some sort of camera follow or the camera is simply a child of the cube.

=> It only looks off since the movement is not being applied in the same direction the camera is facing. But it actually behaves just the way you coded it - using absolute world space positions and direction.

---

Assuming your cube's local forward vector is facing in the correct direction it should be moving in, what you want to do instead is e.g.

```
// In general this is where you should apply Rigidbody physics 
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // if it is about CONTINUOUS user input it is also fine to handle it drectly in FixedUpdate
    
    // Handle rotation first
    if(Input.etKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, -20 * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    }
    
    // then move using the local forward direction
    if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.W))
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + rb.rotation * Vector3.forward * 20 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted